# Pandas one-liner to return column data of head output

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DF with a list of projects and what phases are available for the project.

```
import pandas as pd
projects = {
    'phase': [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
    'projID': ["foo","foo","foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(projects)
```

I wish to return a list of all the project rows where the projID is "bar", but all I have is the phase number (2). So I have a lookup DF that lets me convert the data phase number to the projID:

```
lookup = {"phase":[1,2], "pname": ["bob","frank"]}
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(lookup)
_data_phase = 2
pn = df_tmp.loc[df_tmp['phase'] == _data_phase ,'pname'].head(1)
```

Q1: I want pn to be the value 'frank' as a string, but instead it contains a DataFrame that look like this:

```
1    frank
Name: pname, dtype: object
```

How do I convert that to just the string "frank"? And can that be done as a one-liner?

Q2: Is there a better way to extract the rows from project (`df`) where `_data_phase` = x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the `.values` method or `[0]`. Kindly try:

```
pn = df_tmp.loc[df_tmp['phase'] == _data_phase ,'pname'].values[0]
```

I think that is slicing the dataframe with the specified criteria is a good to get what you need, I wouldn't change it! (You can use other options such as [df.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).